# css-hover working in chrome but not in IE

Tags: jsp, css

When i am open jsp page in chrome css.hover working properly.but in IE it is not working.
following is jsp file

```
<%@page import="java.text.SimpleDateFormat"%>

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://">

<%@ include file="/vw_chksession.jsp" %>
<%@page import="java.util.Date" %>
<html>
<head>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='<%=request.getContextPath()%>/Js/currentTime.js'></script>
<title><bean:message key="app.title" /></title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">


<!-- For Menus CSS Import-->

<link href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/Style/style.css" rel=stylesheet type="text/css"/>
<LINK media=all href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/Style/New_Menu_Style/menus.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<LINK media=all href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/Style/New_Menu_Style/dropdown.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!--[if lte IE 6]><LINK media=all href="</%=request.getContextPath()%>/Style/New_Menu_Style/dropdown_ie.css" type=text/css rel=stylesheet><![endif]-->
<%
   long dt = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Date currentTime = new Date();
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd");
    String today = format.format(currentTime);
%>

</head>

<body onload="startTime();" bottommargin="0" rightmargin="0" topmargin="0" leftmargin="0" bgcolor="WHITE">
<table width="100%" border="2" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
      <td width="400" >&nbsp;&nbsp;<img height="50" src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/index/Logo.bmp"></td>
<!--    <td width="300">&nbsp;</td>-->
    <td width="450" align="center" valign="middle">
        <font size="3" face="Tahoma" color="#043b72">
            <strong>MIRAE ASSET SALES MIS SYSTEM</strong>
        </font>
    </td>
    <td align="right" width="400" valign="top">
        <img src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/index/news_question.gif" border=0 align="absmiddle"> <a href="../help.do" target="mainFrame"><b>Help</b></a> &nbsp;|&nbsp;
        <img src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/index/bronze-star.gif" border=0 align="absmiddle"> <a href="http://mamfapp/Portal/Login.aspx" target="_BLANK" ><b>Portal</b></a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;
    <img src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/index/icon_key.gif" border=0 align="middle"> <a href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/Logout.do" TARGET="_top"><b>Logout</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;</a><br><br>
         <marquee style="height:20;width:200" scrollamount="200" scrolldelay="500">
                <b><div align="center" style= " color: #043b72; height: 4px; width: 180px;" id="txt"></div></b>
         </marquee>
    </td>

  </tr>
  <tr bgcolor="#FF6600" height="22px" >

  </tr>


  <tr bgcolor="#FF6600" height="22px" weight="4">
      <td colspan="2"  style="text-decoration: none; color: #043b72; font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold; text-align: left;">
          <img src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/index/Profile.png" align="absmiddle"/>
          <%=STRuser%> &nbsp;&nbsp;<%=STRname%>&nbsp;&nbsp;<font style="font-weight: lighter;" >[ <%=STRtype%> ]</font>
      </td>
      <td colspan="2" style="text-decoration: none; font-size: 11px; font-weight: bold; text-align: right;">
          <a href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/Home.do" target="mainFrame" style="color: #043b72;">
          Home
          </a>&nbsp;|
          <a href="changePass.do" target="mainFrame" style="color: #043b72;">
          Change Password
          </a>&nbsp;
      </td> </tr>

</table>
<div class="menu">
    <ul>
        <%
            String query="select DISTINCT a.ID,a.CAPTION,a.URL  from EMASTERS.MAST_MENU a,EMASTERS.DATA_MENU_ACCESS B where app_id='4' and a.menu_type='MAIN' "
            +" AND B.ACCESS_USERID='"+STRuserid+"' AND a.ID=B.MENU_ID "
            +"  ORDER BY TO_NUMBER(a.ID)";
            try{
            PreparedStatement ps=null;
            Connection conn=null;
            conn=GEN_Utility.getConnection(STRcon);
            ps=conn.prepareStatement(query);
            ResultSet rs_set=ps.executeQuery();
            System.out.println(" query "+query);
            while(rs_set.next()){
        %>
        <li>
            <a class="" href="#">&nbsp;<%=rs_set.getString(2)%></a>
            <ul>
                <% 
                query="select DISTINCT a.ID,a.CAPTION,a.URL,a.MENU_ORDER  from EMASTERS.MAST_MENU a,EMASTERS.DATA_MENU_ACCESS B where app_id='4' and a.menu_type='SUB' "
                +" AND B.ACCESS_USERID='"+STRuserid+"' AND a.ID=B.MENU_ID AND a.PARENT_ID='"+rs_set.getString(1)+"' "
                +" ORDER BY TO_NUMBER(a.MENU_ORDER)";
                ps=conn.prepareStatement(query);
                ResultSet rs_inner=ps.executeQuery();
                System.out.println(" query----- "+query);
                while(rs_inner.next()){
                System.out.println(" a.CAPTION "+rs_inner.getString(2));
                %>
                <li><a href="<%=request.getContextPath()+"/"%><%=rs_inner.getString(3)%>">&nbsp;<%=rs_inner.getString(2)%></a> 
                </li>
                <%    
                }
                %>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <%
        }///while query
        }catch(Exception E){
        out.println("Exception "+E);
        }
        %>
    </ul>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

dropdown.css

```
.menu {
/*font-size: 11px; z-index: 100; width: 750px; font-family: arial, sans-serif; position: relative; height: 22px; background: #66bbee;*/
/*font-size: 11px; z-index: 100; width: 100%; font-family: arial, sans-serif; position: relative; height: 22px; background: #06285b;#043b72*/
    font-size: 11px;
    z-index: 100;
    width: 100%;
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    position: relative;
    height: 22px;
    background: #043b72;
}

.menu ul li a {
/*border-right: #fff 1px solid; border-top: #fff 1px solid; display: block; font-size: 11px; background: #710069; overflow: hidden; border-left: #fff 1px solid; width: 104px; color: #fff; line-height: 20px; border-bottom: #fff 1px solid; height: 20px; text-align: center; text-decoration: none*/
    border-right: #fff 1px solid;
    border-top: #fff 0 solid;
    display: block;
    font-size: 11px;
    background: #043b72;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-left: #fff 0 solid;
    width: 143px;
    color: #fff;
    line-height: 22px;
    border-bottom: #fff 0 solid;
    height: 21px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.menu ul li a:visited {
/*border-right: #fff 1px solid; border-top: #fff 1px solid; display: block; font-size: 11px; background: #33ccff; overflow: hidden; border-left: #fff 1px solid; width: 104px; color: #fff; line-height: 20px; border-bottom: #fff 1px solid; height: 20px; text-align: center; text-decoration: none*/
    border-right: #fff 1px solid;
    border-top: #fff 0 solid;
    display: block;
    font-size: 11px;
    background: #043b72;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-left: #fff 0 solid;
    width: 143px;
    color: #fff;
    line-height: 22px;
    border-bottom: #fff 0 solid;
    height: 21px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.menu ul {
    padding-right: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding-top: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
}

.menu ul li {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}

.menu ul li ul {
    display: none;
}

/* main menu mouse over */
.menu ul li:hover a {
/*background: #36f; color: #fff*/
/*background: #3399ff; color: #000; text-align: left; border-top: #fff 1px solid;*/
    background: #043b72;
    color: #f60;
    border-top: #fff 1px solid;
}

.menu ul li:hover ul {
    display: block;
    left: 0;
    width: 150px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 21px;
}

/* second level */
.menu ul li:hover ul li a.hide {
/*  background: #6a3; color: #fff*/
    background: #043b72;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: left;
}

.menu ul li:hover ul li:hover a.hide {
/*background: #6fc; color: #000*/
    background: #043b72;
    color: #f60;
}

.menu ul li:hover ul li ul {
    display: none;
}

/* third level */
.menu ul li:hover ul li a {
    display: block;
    background: #043b72;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: left;
}

/*====*/
.menu ul li:hover ul li a:hover {
/*background: #fff; color: #000*/
    background: #043b72;
    color: #f60;
}

.menu ul li:hover ul li:hover ul {
    display: block;
    left: 144px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}

.menu ul li:hover ul li:hover ul.left {
    left: -105px;
}
```

style.css

```
body {
/* background-color:#FFCC66; */
 background-color:#FFFFFF;
 margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
 padding: 0px;
 font: 12px Verdana, Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 color : Fieldsetblack;
}

TABLE {
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: tahoma;
}
TD {
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: tahoma;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
TR {
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: tahoma;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
TH {
    font-size: 11px; font-family: tahoma;
    font-weight: bold;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    text-align: left;
}

radio
{
    font-family:arial;
    font-size:11px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color:#FF6600;
    text-align: left;
}

a:link
{
        /*color:#000000;*/
        color: #06285B;
        font-family:verdana;
        font-size:90%;
        text-decoration:none;
        font-weight: bold;
        /*display:block;*/
        margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;
        padding:0px;
        width:100%;
}

a:visited{
        /*color:#000000;*/
        color: #06285B;
        font-family:verdana;
        font-size:90%;
        text-decoration:none;
        font-weight: bold;
        /*display:block;*/
        margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;
        padding:0px;
/*      width:100%;*/
    }

a:hover{
        color: #FCAF10;
        /*color: #06585B;*/
        font-weight: bold;
        text-decoration:none;
}
a.tool{
        color: #FFFFFF;
        font-weight: bold;
        text-decoration:none;
}

a.tool:hover{
        color: #FFFFFF;
        font-weight: bold;
        text-decoration:none;
}
a.tool:visited{
        color: #FFFFFF;
        font-weight: bold;
        text-decoration:none;
}
.tool{
        color: #FFFFFF;
        font-weight: bold;
        text-decoration:none;
}

.lable
{
    font-family:"Trebuchet MS", Arial, Tahoma;
    font-size:12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color:black;
    text-align: right;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
.lable3
{
    font-family:"Trebuchet MS", Arial, Tahoma;
    font-size:12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color:black;
    text-align: left;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
.lable_dtl
{
    font-family:arial;
    font-size:12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color:black;
    text-align: right;
    vertical-align:middle;
}

.lable1
{
    font-family:arial;
    font-size:12px;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:black;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align:top;
}

.lable2
{
    font-family:arial;
    font-size:11px;
    font-weight:bold;
    /*color:black;*/
    color:white;
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align:middle;  
    background: #06285B;

}

.btn {
    background: url(btnimg.bmp) repeat-x; color: #ffffff; font-weight: bold; line-height: 20px; cursor: hand
}

input,textarea,select,option{
    color:black;
    /*background:#FFFFCC;*/
    background:#EBF2FA;
    font-family:arial;
    font-weight: none;
    font-size:12px;
}

radio,checkbox{ 
background: #FFFFFF;
}


.textdata
{
    font-family:arial;
    font-size:12px;
    font-weight: none;
    /*color:#993300;*/
    color:black;
    /*color:black;*/

}

form
{
margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
 padding: 0px;
}

.toolbar
{
/*background: #06285B;*/
/*background: #FCAF10;*/
background: #FFFFFF;
/* font-size:15px; */
font-size:12px;
/*color: #FFFFFF;*/
color: #06285B;
font-weight: bold;
font-family:verdana;

}

.btnCreate {
    /*background: url(/MARS/Images/BackImage.jpg) repeat-x; */
    background: #043B72;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 14px;
    cursor: hand;
}

.cancelButton{
    /*background: url(/MARS/Images/BackImage.jpg) repeat-x; */
    background: #043B72;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 14px;
    cursor: hand;
    text-decoration:none;
}


#footer {

    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

.xstooltip
{
    visibility: hidden; 
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 2;

    font: normal 8pt sans-serif;
    padding: 3px;
    border: solid 1px;

    background-color: #FFFFCC;
   /* background-image: url(images/blue.png);*/
}

fieldset{
    border: solid 2px;
    border-color: #043B72;
    /*border-color: #06285B;*/
}
table.repTable {
    border-width: 3px;
    border-spacing: 0px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: navy;
    border-collapse: collapse;  
}
table.repTable th {
    border-width: 2px;
    padding: 2px; 
    border-style: inset;
    border-color: navy;
    background-color: #143B72;
    text-align: center;
}
table.repTable td {
    border-width: 1px;
    padding: 2px;
    border-style: inset;
    border-color: gray; 
    text-align: left;
}
```

Comment: What is your ie version?

Answer (score 1):

Add `<!DOCTYPE html>` as the first line of your HTML.

Remove `<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://">`

Answer (score 1):

The issue is very likely to be with your doctype, but there are two separate issues at work here, and one of them  is quite a subtle bug.

Let's deal with the easy one first:

The doctype you're currently using is a terrible choice of doctype:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://">
```

This is the HTML4.01 Transitional doctype. It is very *very* old. It dates back to the days when IE6 was being launched and most people were on IE5. It is one of the few doctypes that causes the browser to go into "almost standards mode". This is a half-way mode between the old busted Quirks mode and the modern Standards mode. It is a really bad idea to be using this mode, because it is poorly documented and non-standard. You will get cross browser issues using this doctype.

I therefore strongly recommend switching to the more modern HTML5 doctype:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

That's the easy bit, and it will solve some of your cross-browser bugs. However it won't fix the specific problem in your question. So now for the more subtle bug, which is actually what is giving you issues:

IE (and other browsers) will throw the page into quirks mode if the page doesn't have a valid doctype. You probably already know this.

However, what you probably don't know is that some IE versions have a bug whereby if there is anything before the doctype -- even just a blank line -- it will cause the browser to see the doctype as invalid.

I see that your code begins like this:

```
<%@page import="java.text.SimpleDateFormat"%>

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://">

<%@ include file="/vw_chksession.jsp" %>
```

Note the blank line before the doctype. This is very likely to be causing your page to go into quirks mode.

The solution is to remove that blank line. This should take the browser out of quirks mode, and resolve your hover issues.

So combining the two points together, your code should now look like this:

```
<%@page import="java.text.SimpleDateFormat"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<%@ include file="/vw_chksession.jsp" %>
```

I hope that helps.